# MySQL set a variable when a join is made

Tags: mysql, sql

I have in my database two tables, `videos` and `watched`.

The `videos` table contains videos along with their metadata, and its primary key is `video_id`.

The `watched` table contains information about videos already watched by users. Its key is `video_id`+`user_id`.

I want to create a query that will return all the videos from `videos` table and add a column with value `true` for videos that exist in `watched` table.

The pseudocode can look like this:

```
SELECT a,b,c, IF(video_is_watched, true, false) AS watched FROM videos
LEFT JOIN watched ON watched.user_id = "user-id"
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Does this mean that you want 'watched' to be true for videos that were watched by *any* user, not per specific user? This statement implies such an answer: "I want to create a query that will return all the videos from videos table and add a column with value true for videos that exist in watched table."  They key phrase is "exist in watched table" rather than "exist in watched table for the specific user". Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a case statement to check for null value in w.video_Id it will be NULL when not watched.

```
SELECT V.a, v.b, v.c, 
       case when w.video_ID is null then FALSE else TRUE end as UserWatched
FROM videos v
LEFT JOIN watched w
  ON V.video_ID  w.Video_ID
 and w.user_id = "user-id"
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much, your solution worked! Actually I tried a similar code with IF instead of case (`IF(w.video_id IS NULL, false, true) AS watched`), but I did join only on `user_id` without `video_id`, which made my code not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `exists` to create the flag:

```
select v.*,
       (exists (select 1 from watched where w.video_id = v.video_id and w.user_id = "$userid")
       ) as UserWatchedVideoFlag
form vidoes v;
```